# ReactNative: error Cannot read property 'RNFSFIleTypeRegular' of null

Tags: react-native

As of React Native version 0.60 and above, the react-native link command is no longer required for most libraries, including react-native-fs. Instead, we can use the auto-linking feature provided by React Native.

But when I try to `import RNFS from 'react-native-fs'`, I get this error!!!

[image: this]

Why is that so?

package.json

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "expo": "^48.0.7",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-font": "^11.1.1",
    "expo-linking": "~4.0.1",
    "expo-router": "^1.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.3",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.4.8",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.9.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.14.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "metro": "^0.73.7",
    "metro-resolver": "^0.73.7"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "metro": "^0.73.7",
    "metro-resolver": "^0.73.7"
  },
  "name": "react_native_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true
}
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, TextInput, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import XLSX from 'xlsx';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const ROWS = 10;
const COLS = 5;

const HomeScreen = function (navigation) {
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState([]);

  // Initialize an empty grid on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    initializeGrid();
  }, []);

  // Function to initialize an empty grid
  const initializeGrid = () => {
    const emptyGrid = Array.from({ length: ROWS }, () => Array(COLS).fill(''));
    setGridData(emptyGrid);
  };

  // Load saved data from AsyncStorage on component mount
  useEffect(() => {
    loadGridData();
  }, []);

  // Function to load saved data from AsyncStorage
  const loadGridData = async () => {
    try {
      const data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('gridData');
      if (data) {
        setGridData(JSON.parse(data));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading data from AsyncStorage:', error);
    }
  };

  // Function to save grid data to AsyncStorage
  const saveGridData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('gridData', JSON.stringify(gridData));
      Alert.alert('Success', 'Grid data saved!');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving data to AsyncStorage:', error);
    }
  };

  // Function to handle input field change
  const handleInputChange = (rowIndex, colIndex, value) => {
    const updatedGridData = [...gridData];
    updatedGridData[rowIndex] = [...updatedGridData[rowIndex]]; // Create a new array for the row
    updatedGridData[rowIndex][colIndex] = value;
    setGridData(updatedGridData);
  };

  // Function to handle download button click
  const handleDownload = () => {
    const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    const sheetData = gridData.map((row) => row.map((cell) => ({ v: cell })));
    const worksheet = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(sheetData);
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, worksheet, 'Sheet1');
    const file = XLSX.write(workbook, { type: 'base64', bookType: 'xlsx' });

    // Save the file to mobile storage
    // Here, you would need to use a library or platform-specific APIs to save the file.
    // For example, you can use the `react-native-fs` library to save the file to the device's storage.
    // Refer to the library documentation for the specific implementation details.

    // Example using `react-native-fs` library:
    //
    // const path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/ameya-test.xlsx';
    // RNFS.writeFile(path, file, 'base64')
    //   .then(() => {
    //     Alert.alert('Success', 'Excel file saved!');
    //   })
    //   .catch((error) => {
    //     console.error('Error saving file:', error);
    //   });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Button title="Download" onPress={handleDownload} />
      </View>
      <View>
        {gridData.map((row, rowIndex) => (
          <View key={rowIndex} style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
            {row.map((cell, colIndex) => (
              <TextInput
                key={colIndex}
                style={{ flex: 1, borderWidth: 1, padding: 5 }}
                value={cell}
                onChangeText={(value) =>
                  handleInputChange(rowIndex, colIndex, value)
                }
              />
            ))}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

Comment: May I suggest you use the expo-file-system package instead of react-native-fs because some methods are responsible for that error? In my case, it was the readFile method. I can drop a sample code to download a generated .xlsx file to your device using the expo-file-system.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is an alternative approach using:

```
npx expo install expo-file-system
```

instead of:

```
react-native-fs
```

In my case, some methods like the `readFile` method created that error in my project.

```
import FileSystem from "expo-file-system"
```

Next you create a callback function to output the progress of the download:

```
const callback = (downloadProgress) => {
    const progress = downloadProgress.totalBytesWritten / downloadProgress.totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
    console.log(progress);
}
```

Next, create a download resumable instance to allow you to pause and resume the download.

```
const downloadResumable = FileSystem.createDownloadResumable(
    'https://sheetjs.com/pres. Numbers',
    FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'data.xlsx',
    {},
    callback
);
```

You can now finally call the `downloadAsync` method from the `downloadResumable` instance to save your file to your device.

```
try {
    const { uri } = await downloadResumable.downloadAsync();
    console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
} catch (e) {
    console. Error(e);
}
```

Here is a link to the full documentation: [Expo FileSystem Documentation](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/)